# Mapping in automapper based on a variable

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using Automapper for mapping my dtos. I have a tricky scenario where I want to map on condition.

```
if (countryCode == "")

    CreateMap<src, dest>()                
                .ForMember(dest => dest.CountryOriginCode, 
                            act => act.MapFrom(src => 
                 src.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Key == "CountryExportCode").Value))

else

    CreateMap<src, dest>()                
                .ForMember(dest => dest.CountryOriginCode, 
                            act => act.MapFrom(src => 
                 src.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Key == "CountryOriginCode").Value))
```

I have 2 requirements here.

1. I want to map it conditionally
2. How can I get the value of CountryCode which is in another object say CountryObject

Edit -

CreateMap<country, countryDto>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.CountryCode, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.CountryCode))

```
CreateMap<src, dest>()                
.ForMember(
    dest => dest.CountryOriginCode, 
    act => act.MapFrom(src => countryCode == CountryCode ? // Observer the CountryCode , I need it from above 
        src.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Key == "CountryExportCode").Value:
        src.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Key == "CountryOriginCode").Value)
)
```

Comment: Write the `countryCode` check _inside_ the `MapFrom`.

Comment: What do you mean "I need it from above" ? Where does this CountryCode come from ? Is it the same for all objects ? Will it be the same for any existing mapping you'll ever do from `src` to `dest` ?

Comment: CountryCode comes from another mapping ---------- CreateMap<country, countryDto>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.CountryCode, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.CountryCode))

Comment: So, you want a conditional mapping from a value that a) you only know at runtime and b) isn't a property on the object you want to map? In that case, I don't see how this can be done with AutoMapper, though I might be wrong.

Comment: a. Yes , I want it at runtime

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to do this in AutoMapper, rather than add an `if` statement in your code?

Comment: @stuartd -- Yes , if I do in my code I end up using For Loops.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
CreateMap<src, dest>()                
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.CountryOriginCode, 
        act => act.MapFrom(src => countryCode == "" ?
            src.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Key == "CountryExportCode").Value:
            src.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Key == "CountryOriginCode").Value)
    )
```

Comment: What if I want to get the value of CountryCode from another object . How can I achieve that ?

Comment: @amitagarwal you should add to your question.